# How to display Jquery modal dialog after server side validation error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am very new to JQuery and MVC. In my application i am opening a JQuery modal dialog on button click. I am rendering a partial view on this dialog using controller action method which is something like:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{                     
  return PartialView("Create");
}
```

Partial view contains some textboxes and "create" button. On create button i am trying to save data in database. But before that i do some validation like if entered name already exist then show that message to user.
I did this using following code:

```
return PartialView("Create", model);
```

this is showing the message properly but it render only partial view in browser and modal dialog gets disappeared.

Please let me know how can i show the same modal dialog with error.

Answer (score 11):

You will need to use AJAX submit of the form. Here's how to proceed. As always start with a view model which will represent the information for the dialog form:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The bar is absolutely required")]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView("Create");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return PartialView(model);
        }
        // TODO: the model is valid => do some processing with it
        // and return a JSON result confirming the success
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
}
```

and a main view (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Remark: all this javascript could be placed in a separate js file
    // to avoid cluttering the views
    $(function () {
        $('#modalLink').click(function () {
            $('#dialog').load(this.href, function () {
                $(this).dialog();
                bindForm(this);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

    function bindForm(dialog) {
        $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        alert('thanks for submitting');
                        $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                    } else {
                        $('#dialog').html(result);
                        bindForm();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
</script>


@Html.ActionLink("open modal", "create", null, null, new { id = "modalLink" })
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

and a partial view (`~/Views/Home/Create.cshtml`) which will contain the form shown in the modal:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Foo)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Foo)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Bar)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Bar)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Bar)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```